# In-App purchase SKProduct not received from SKProductsRequest

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, skproduct

I had 3 In-App purchases (non-renewable subscriptions) in the App store connect account, all Approved and retrieved in the code successfully

Then I added one more free non-renewable subscription In-App purchase, submitted to the app store New In-App purchase is Approved, all agreements are active, tax and banking info is ok, product identifier in the code is the same as in the App Store connect

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I request all four products in SKProductsRequest But in the productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) I receive three old In-App purchase SKProducts, but product identifier of the new In-App purchase is received in invalidProductIdentifiers

```
func fetchProducts() {
    let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: ["mentalmind.kz.free", "mentalmind.kz.threemonth", "mentalmind.kz.sixmonth", "mentalmind.kz.oneyear"])
    request.delegate = self
    request.start()
}

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("received products: \(response.products.map({ $0.productIdentifier }))")
    print("invalid product ids: \(response.invalidProductIdentifiers)")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.products = response.products
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
received products: ["mentalmind.kz.oneyear", "mentalmind.kz.sixmonth", "mentalmind.kz.threemonth"] 
invalid product ids: ["mentalmind.kz.free"]
```

Is it Apple's fault, or you have any code recommendations for me?

Comment: Nobody can tell since you don't show a single line of code.

Comment: @ElTomato , added code and screenshots

Comment: To my knowledge, the only chance that `StoreKit` doesn't recognize all your products is that the product identifier you specify in your app is different from the one you have actually registered at iTunes Connect.  Another small possibility is that you didn't wait long enough till their server propagates data.

Comment: @ElTomato , yes, that is what thought too, but I copy pasted the identifier from App Store Connect and I added this In-App purchase more than one week ago :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not know what was the issue, Apple support did not help me
But I created new In-App Purchase with cheapest price, but not free and it worked fine in the App Store Connect
May be problem was because the In-App purchase was free